# Get the purchase history of a user including prices/items

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a web application. Users need to buy different packs of credits to use this web application. For instance, one pack of 5000 credits costs 4.99 USD; one pack of 10000 credits costs 7.99 USD. I use Stripe to manage the purchase. I can use the following code to create a checkout session where users can adjust the quantity to buy `priceId`.

```
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      customer: customer.id,
      mode: "payment",
      line_items: [
        {
          price: priceId,
          quantity: 1,
          adjustable_quantity: {
            enabled: true,
            minimum: 1,
            maximum: 10,
          },
        },
      ],
      success_url: successUrl,
      expand: ['line_items'],
    });
```

Then, given a user, I would like to write a function to get his purchase history. I'm thinking of using `stripe.charges.list`. But in a charge, we know the amount the user paid, we don't know what price/item he bought. Does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could save all the information in your database at the time a payment happens by handling a webhook, and then you can query what you need. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders
- You can list CheckoutSessions by a Stripe customer ID (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list#list_checkout_sessions-customer) and expand the `data.line_items` [field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items) (https://stripe.com/docs/expand#lists) to see what the customer bought in that Session.

Comment: I finally used checkout sessions.